# Apply Cauchy integral formula to product

Tags: combinatorics, complex-analysis, derivatives, residue-calculus, cauchy-integral-formula

Given that

$$
\frac{d^nf(z)}{dz^n} \bigg|_{z=z_0}=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\oint \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^{n+1}}dz
$$

Can we apply the same formula to a product of the form $g(z) = z^mf(z)$? For instance

$$
\frac{d^n }{dz^n}[z^mf(z)]\bigg|_{z=z_0}=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\oint \frac{z^mf(z)}{(z-z_0)^{n+1}}dz
$$

Comment: If you expect people to put in the effort to answer a question, then it is polite to put in some effort yourself. For example, simply telling us where you got the problem from or explaining what you tried would be a big step forward! (For further feedback/help with asking questions, you can ask [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43593/constructive-feedback).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one you've written is correct because $z^mf(z)$ is holomorphic if you know that $f$ is holomorphic on the given domain.

Comment: Please do not answer PSQs ("Problem statement questions"). This is against the math.se policy. See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards) for more information.